# How to extract percentile values using Xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm using xarray to extract data from a NetCDF file (.nc). I need to extract the 75th percentile value for one of the variables (concentration of chemical) at each time step across a set of dimensions (latitude, longitude, depth). I'm using the below code to do this

```
df = xr.open_dataset("10y_125_365_concentration.nc") 
c_75 = df.concentration.quantile(0.75, dim=('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth'))
```

The result gives '0' as output for first few time steps before giving specific values of concentration. It appears that the code calculates 75th percentile values across entire array, however, I need to extract 75 percentile values excluding the zeros in the array (the length of the concentration array with values other than 0 changes with time and the number of zero values decreases as time step increases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xr.DataArray.quantile`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.quantile.html) has an optional argument `skipna` which defaults to `True` for `float` data types. So by default, if `df.concentration` has float data, xarray will use `np.nanpercentile` under the hood and will skip invalid data.

So, all you need to do is tell xarray that 0s are invalid and should be skipped. You can do this with [`DataArray.where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html), which will return `np.nan` anywhere the condition is `False`:

```py
c_75 = df.concentration.where(df.concentration != 0).quantile(
    0.75, dim=('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth')
)
```

***Performance note:*** currently, [`np.nanpercentile` is much, *much* slower than `np.percentile`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16575) when operating over a subset of the axes of a high-dimensional array (e.g. most xarray use cases). This seems unavoidable in your case, but in other cases where you do not have invalid values in your array, it's best to pass `skipna=False` to allow xarray to use the much faster `np.percentile` operation under the hood. Careful with this though - `np.percentile` returns incorrect results if NaNs are present.

Comment: The suggested solutions works fine. Appreciate your detailed explanation of the answer, its really helpful to a newbee like me in Xarray. Just one question: I believe the suggested solution `df.concentration.where(df.concentration != 0)` will avoid both NaNs and zeros in an array right? I'm not sure if I've NaNs in addition to zeros in array.

Comment: yeah - this would skip both zeros and NaNs. There's no standard way to handle NaNs in a quantiling operation *other* than to skip them as far as I'm aware... if you wanted to treat the NaNs as some value you could always fill the prior nans with `df.concentration.fillna(FILL_VALUE).where(df.concentration != 0).quantile` - you could even fill with 0s here and they'd be considered in the quantiling operation as long as you do this in one line like this.

Comment: Ok...if I understand correctly both of this `df.concentration.fillna(0).where(df.concentration != 0).quantile(0.75, dim=('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth'))` and `df.concentration.where(df.concentration != 0).quantile(0.75, dim=('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth'))` should give the same output? However, there are several zeros in the first alternative compared to none in 2nd alternative.  Am I making some error here or?

Comment: `df.concentration.fillna(0).where(df.concentration != 0)` will actually result in zeros wherever your data previously had NaNs (and NaNs where previously 0), since the `.where` is masking wherever `df.concentration` is zero, not `df.concentration.fillna(0)`. so you must have NaNs in your data. I'm not sure what you want to do with those - you can skip them or assign them to zero or 9999 or do whatever you want :)

Comment: I just need to skip both NaNs and Zeros when calculating quantile values, and I'm not really sure if I have NaNs or Zeros or both in an array. If i assign NaN some value they will somehow interact with the quantile calculation. So, if this command can skip both NaN and Zero I'm good to go `df.concentration.where(df.concentration != 0).quantile(0.75, dim=('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth'))` could you please confirm this?

Comment: yep - exactly. that will turn 0s into NaNs and leave pre-existing NaNs as they are, and both will be skipped in the quantiling

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and explanation, appreciate it :)

Comment: no problem! welcome to xarray :D it's a great library